# VSTO Addin - Add dockable window to VBE Editor

Tags: c#, vba, vbe

I'm making a VSTO Addin for PowerPoint in C#, which adds a better project explorer. I've been making it in a userform, however it would be better if the window would be part of the VBE editor (aka dockable). I found the `CreateToolWindow` function in `Application.VBE.Windows.CreateToolWindow`. However, I don't know how to use this function, or if it even does what I'm trying to do. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtoolwindow-method) say very little about it and I couldn't find any examples on the internet. How do I get the Addin instance? What is ProgId? What is a UserDocument?

This is my base code:

```
namespace PowerPointAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        public static PowerPoint.Application App;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.VBE.Windows.CreateToolWindow(/*...*/);
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

VSTO add-ins are not designed for customizing the VBA editor. It seems you need to develop a COM add-in for the Visual Basic for Applications editor, not PowerPoint. To get that done you need to implement the `IDTExtensibility2` interface. Typically your implementation will have `Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")` and `ProgId("YourAddins.UserControlHost")` attributes for the class (which implements the COM add-ins interface).

> How do I get the Addin instance?

`ThisAddin` is your add-in instance (use `this` in C#). Typically when you implement the `IDTExtensibility2` interface the instance is passed as a parameter to the `Connect` method.

> What is ProgId?

This is a name of your add-in. Typically you can find it in the windows registry or in the `ProgID` attribute specified for the add-in class.

> What is a UserDocument?

The document that should be displayed in the editor.

You may find the sample code in the [Create a toolwindow for the VBA editor with .NET(C#).](https://www.cnblogs.com/Charltsing/p/VBEtoolwindow.html) article.

Comment: Ok, so I have to make a COM Addin. I tried making one using [this tutorial](https://bettersolutions.com/csharp/excel-interop/com-add-ins.htm), but it doesn't quite work. It shows up it in the VB References list in the VBE Editor, but doesn't run the `OnConnection` function. I have followed all the steps and used the same code as the one from the tutorial.

Comment: The guide mentioned describes an Excel COM add-in, not VBA. You need to register it for the VBE environment. Checking/adding a reference in the VBA editor is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this web archive (written by Carlos Quintero, the main MzTool contributor) :
https://web.archive.org/web/20211024050815/https://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012017.aspx

You'll find in that webpage many other usefull links to create vbe addins !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32905150)